# Fullcalendar : how to get click time from eventClick callback?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using Fullcalendar v4 with TimeGrid view and i need to **get the time of the click inside an Event**.

the eventClick callbacks  has one parameter called **eventClickInfo** that is a Plain Object with that attributes:

- **event** The associated Event Object.
- **el** The HTML element for this event.
- **jsEvent** The native JavaScript event with low-level information such as click coordinates.
- **view** The current View Object

I searched inside the jsEvent and i got the coordinates of the click but i not found the time clicked. Maybe do you know how to convert Y coordinate to time using TimeGrid View ?

Another solution i found is using dateClick event  instead of eventClick, because dateClick gave me the time of the click, but unfortunately dateClick is not triggered when the click is inside the event. Maybe do you know a way to trigger dateClick also when the click is inside an Event ?

all other ideas are welcome, thank you !

[eventClick documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)

[dateClick documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick)

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want, sorry. FullCalendar won't give you the exact time within the clicked event. Can I ask _why_ you want to do this? What is the precise purpose of knowing this time within the event...what will you use it for? I ask because maybe there is another way to meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank You @ADyson , i have a calendar with disponibility events, when a disponibility is clicked i open a modal with a form to book an appointment, i wanted to precompile the hour of the appointment with the time clicked inside the disponibility.
it would also be enough for me to approximate the time clicked, i don't need the exact time.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "disponsibility"? It's not a common word in English. Do you mean "availability" perhaps? So, if you are using events to show available time, then you're using the calendar in the opposite way to how it's intended. Events should be used to show time which is **not** available, i.e. where an appointment has already been made.

Comment: If you want to show available times, then there are some possible options: 1) use [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours) to show regular times when appointments are available, and mark other times outside those hours automatically as unavailable. If that's not flexible enough then I would recommend 2) Using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) to mark available areas - that way you can allow the user to still select times on top of that.

Comment: And if you're using the timeGrid view, then if you use the [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callback (instead of dateClick or eventClick), then a) the user can drag-and-drop to select the start and end dates they require, and b) the calendar will tell you the start and end dates they selected.

Comment: I'll try your solutions, thank you very much !